# how to insert the data into pixels faster?

Tags: python, image

I'm currently working on a steagnographic application,
and i'm taking each pixel value and embedding data into it one by one
this sequencial processing is taking a long time to process,

the code:

```
    import config_loader
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import encryption
import time


def byte2bin(bytestring):
    # print("\n from byte 2 bin\n")
    # print(bytestring)
    bitstring = bin(int.from_bytes(bytestring, byteorder="big"))
    return bitstring[2:]


def insert_data_in_pixel(raw_data, string, ptr, bits=1):  # this function takes a pixel's data and then converts it to
                                                          # binary and then change the last bit to the secret
    color = bin(int(raw_data))[2:]
    # old = color                                                   # troubleshooting lines
    color = color[:len(color) - bits]
    color = color + string[ptr: ptr + bits]
    # print("original-> ", old,"| |added bits ",string[ptr: ptr+bits],"| |Modified-> ", color)  # troubleshooting lines
    return np.uint8(int(color, 2))


def insert_length(length, new_img):  # inserts length of our secret and the length itself is obfuscated
    secret_string_len = '<l>' + str(int(length / 4) + 16) + '<l>'  # Added ambiguity
    secret_string_len = ''.join(format(_, '08b') for _ in bytearray(str(secret_string_len), encoding='utf-8'))
    length = len(secret_string_len)
    str_len_ptr = 0

    for y in range(length):
        x = 0
        if str_len_ptr < length:
            new_img[x][y][0] = insert_data_in_pixel(new_img[x][y][0], secret_string_len, str_len_ptr, bits=3)
            str_len_ptr += 3
            if str_len_ptr == length:
                break
            new_img[x][y][1] = insert_data_in_pixel(new_img[x][y][1], secret_string_len, str_len_ptr, bits=3)
            str_len_ptr += 3
            if str_len_ptr == length:
                break
            new_img[x][y][2] = insert_data_in_pixel(new_img[x][y][2], secret_string_len, str_len_ptr, bits=2)
            str_len_ptr += 2
            if str_len_ptr == length:
                break


def secret_Loader():  # loads secret from a file
    with open('Message.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    message = ''.join(lines)

    key = config_loader.read('''data['key']''')
    # print(key)
    enc_message = encryption.encrypt(message, key)
    return enc_message


def insert():
    start = time.time()

    image_path = config_loader.read('''data['environment']['cover_image']''')
    photo = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')  # just insert the image name here
    data = np.asarray(photo).copy()
    width, height = photo.size


    secret = byte2bin(secret_Loader())
    secret_pointer = 0

    lensecret = len(secret)
    insert_length(lensecret, data)

    insertion = time.time()
    for x in range(1, height):
        for y in range(width):
            if lensecret > secret_pointer:

                # RED
                data[x][y][0] = insert_data_in_pixel(data[x][y][0], secret, secret_pointer, bits=2)
                secret_pointer += 2
                if lensecret == secret_pointer:
                    break

                # Green
                data[x][y][1] = insert_data_in_pixel(data[x][y][1], secret, secret_pointer, bits=2)
                secret_pointer += 2
                if lensecret == secret_pointer:
                    break

                # Blue
                data[x][y][2] = insert_data_in_pixel(data[x][y][2], secret, secret_pointer, bits=1)
                secret_pointer += 1
                if lensecret == secret_pointer:
                    break

    print("data insertion",time.time()-insertion)
    generation = time.time()
    # print(data)
    data = Image.fromarray(data)
    print("image generation in ", time.time()-generation)
    # data.show()
    _ = time.time()
    data = data.save(r'stg.PNG')
    print("saving time ", time.time()-_)
    print('Exectuted in->', time.time() - start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    insert()
```

the timings

```
encryption in  1.0841524600982666
data insertion 9.439783811569214
image generation in  0.039893388748168945
saving time  6.283206939697266
Exectuted in-> 17.11327576637268
```

I thought about multithreading but that is unreliable as every bit in the data is important and it's position in the sequence is also important.

P.S the data insertion time is for 10000
lines of this

```
this is a message to test the limit of the program let's check when it breaks and how, also i'm running out of words0
```

so this isn't bad but if it can be improved how can i achieve it?

Comment: Leave multithreading, the source of your issue is the double-for loop. Try rewriting the algorithm in a vectorized way and it will be much, much faster.

Comment: so where do i learn to vectorize?